# Como posso refatorar essa mutation vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, refatoração, vuex

Eu tenho o seguinte cenário: eu estou manipulando o objeto `namespaced questions`, dentro dele existe `list` e `news`, quero criar um `mutation` que adicione um par chave valor nas `questions` dentro desses dois `arrays`.

Quero uma função genérica que saiba em qual dos dois arrays está, e altere aquela question específica.

```
const SET_TYPING_COMMENT = (state, question) => {
    state.list = [
        ...state.list.map(_question => {
            if (_question.id == question.id) {
                _question = { ..._question, typing: true };
            }
            return _question;
        })
    ];

    state.news = [
        ...state.news.map(_question => {
            if (_question.id == question.id) {
                _question = { ..._question, typing: true };
            }
            return _question;
        })
    ];
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
const changeQuestionState = (state, type, {id}, typing) => {
  return state[type].map(_question => {
    return { 
      ..._question, 
      typing: _question.id == id ? Boolean(typing): _question.typing
    };
  });
}

const SET_TYPING_COMMENT = (state, question) => {
  ['list', 'news'].forEach(type => {
    state[type] = changeQuestionState(state, type, question, true);
  });
};
```

A ideia é criar uma função que receba tudo o que precisa para retornar o array com o novo estado.
Podes também fazer o `state.list =` mais DRY com `['list', 'news'].forEach(type => {`

**Nota:** Quando usas o `.map()` não precisas do operador *spread*, o `.map()` não muda a array original.

---

Se quiseres colocar essa nova função dentro do action não precisas de tantos argumentos...

```js
const SET_TYPING_COMMENT = (state, question) => {
  ['list', 'news'].forEach(type => {
    state[type] = state[type].map(_question => {
      return {
        ..._question,
        typing: _question.id == question.id ? Boolean(typing) : _question.typing
      };
    });
  });
};
```